# TableView didSelectRowAt not being called when nested in views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following structure UIViewController -> UIView -> UIView -> UITableView (it's a dropdown menu), and the method didSelectRowAt is not being called, but if I skip the first view (that after VC), everything working perfectly. I saw a similar question here where was stated that you should use the method `bringSubviewToFront` but I tried that and it's not working (maybe I did it wrong).
Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let someView = someView()
        someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(someView)
    }
}

class someView: UIView {
    
    public lazy var button: DropDownButton = {
        let button = DropDownButton(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("Colors", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["1","2","1","2"]
        button.dropView.delegate = self
        return button
    }()
    init() {
        
        super.init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
        addSubview(button)
        addSubview(scrollButtons)
        setUpConstraints()
    }
}
class DropDownButton: UIButton {
    
    public var dropView = DropDownView()
    private var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
    private var isOpen = false
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        
        dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }
    
    func dismissDropDown() {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.5,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
            options: .curveEaseInOut,
            animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isOpen == false {
            
            isOpen = true
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                           options: .curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)
            
        } else {
            isOpen = false
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.3,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                options: .curveEaseInOut,
                animations: {
                    self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                    self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            
        }
    }
}
class DropDownView: UIView {
    
    var dropDownOptions = [String]()
    
    var tableView = UITableView()
    
    weak var delegate: DropDownDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.addSubview(tableView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
}

extension DropDownView: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dropDownOptions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell
    }
}

extension DropDownView: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("cell pressed")
        self.delegate?.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to run this - for example, what is `DropDownButton`? What is `DropDownDelegate`? What are `scrollButtons` and where is `setupConstraints()`? Most likely, you have not constrained the views correctly. Add this line: `someView.clipsToBounds = true` at the end of `viewDidLoad()` ... if you no longer see anything, that's the problem.

Comment: How do you initialise your dropDownOptions string array ?